# Not able to login to AWS ECR Repository through docker login command

Tags: amazon-web-services

Not able to login to AWS ECR Repository through docker login command.
Using command - 
docker login REPO_URL

After I enter username and password the result is 401 Unauthorized.

What could be the issue ?

Comment: What commands are you running?

Comment: I was able to login. Dint used AWS ecr get login command first to get the docker login command.

Answer (score 7):

In my case this worked:

aws ecr get-login-password 
--region  
| docker login 
--username AWS 
--password-stdin <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr..amazonaws.com

it was on page
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login-password.html

Comment: Note that regardless of the IAM users you may already have in your account, you SHOULD use username `AWS`..., which is a system user.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
aws ecr get-login-password \
    --region MYREGION \
| docker login \
    --username AWS \
    --password-stdin ACCOUNTID.dkr.ecr.MYREGION.amazonaws.com
```

Copy paste it in the terminal and replace the placeholders (`MYREGION` and `ACCOUNTID`)

Answer (score 3):

You need to first request for the authorization token from ECR using AWS CLI and then extract the password from it and then, call docker login command.

Refer - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-authorization-token.html

Answer (score 2):

Do this to login: $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)

Comment: How do you know this will answer the question at hand? Maybe this is the exact command they have already run. Answers should have some context, not just a blob of command line.

Comment: This is a recommended way of quickly and simply logging into ECR via Docker: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login.html

Comment: This command is not compatible with AWS CLI Version 2

Comment: `get-login` has changed to `get-login-password` at v2